# Drupal 7 Lists the organic groups current user is a member

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, organic-groups

I want show in profile page the lists of organic groups that current user is a member.
By default if i call `<?php print render($user_profile); ?>` on my result i have one field with the list of my groups membership.
But I can not intercept the function or variable that generates this result.
How i can obtain this with drupal 7? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the direct access for this

```
<?php print render ($user_profile['og_user_node']); ?>
```

Or we can also create a simple view block for profile page..the og module already provides these views by default.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `og_get_groups_by_user()` to get group of current user.

```php
$groups = og_get_groups_by_user($account);
```

This will return group IDs of all the groups this user is an approved member of.

Comment: Where does this go?